# My Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not showing up (only when I'm not on localhost) and its causing a CORS error

Tags: next.js, cors, gcloud

I'm trying to create a personal website hosted on GCloud using next.js. I press a button on my home page and want to be served information from the backend. When I press the button on the webpage hosted on GCloud, it triggers the endpoint which is supposed to respond with information, but I get a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxyyzz/api/handlereq' from origin 'https://xxyyzz' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

        
GET https://xxyyzz/api/handlereq net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

In case its useful, the method I'm using to make this fetch is:

```
  async function queryAPI() {
    const response = await fetch(https://xxyyzz/api/handlereq, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    const data = await response.json();
  }
```

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-cors-next-js-handle-cross-origin-requests/) to try and fix the issue, so I have a next.config.js file in which it sets `key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*"`

However, when I press the button to trigger the handler, there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the network tab for that response. I tried running the page on my machine at localhost:3000, and when I press the same button on that, it works just fine (I get my information from the backend) and in the response headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present with value of *:

So I can only assume that the config is not running when it is on GCloud, or at least not in time? Because otherwise I would think there would be that header on the response and I wouldn't have this error.

I also tried running middleware instead of the next.config.js file but that didn't work for me either, although I'm not sure if I did it correctly. I don't know of any other way to put headers on the responses from my backend. (I've also looked at the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) but it didn't seem to help me.)

Is there a way I can fix this?